# Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\Blueprint::increments()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I'm new at laravel 4 and in my first project when I try to migrate this I got this error :

> Migration table created successfully.
>       {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call
>   to      undefiend method
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::increments()","file":"foo","line:19"}}

And this my migration code in `app\migration\2014_10_14_114343_add_cats_and_breeds_table.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddCatsAndBreedsTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cats', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('date_of_birth')->nullable();
        $table->integer('breed_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('breeds', function($table){
        $table->incremetns('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('cats');
    Schema::drop('breeds');
}

}
```

Can any one help me correct the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a typo.

Instead of:

```
$table->incremetns('id');
```

should be

```
$table->increments('id');
```